# Razor pages action tag helper does not generate query parameter

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am following this msdn example [Add Column Sort Links to the Students Index Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page)

And exactly like the example am trying to add links to my current page with some additional query parameters.

While using (exactly as the msdn example)

```
<a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sort="foo">Link</a>
```

The query parameter is not generated. The link i get is the same as my current url.

```
https://localhost:44346/clients
```

If i add the controller also on the tag helper , everything works fine.

```
<a asp-controller="Clients" asp-action="Index" asp-route-sort="foo">Link</a>
```

And i get

```
https://localhost:44346/Clients?sort=foo
```

Comment: Your question title and tags reference Razor pages but looks like your following a standard MVC example. Razor pages are a new separate thing in asp.net core 2

Comment: Also have you downloaded the example code and run that? Does that also have the controller tag added or is there some other difference between that and your code.

Comment: true that, but why would tag-helpers behave differently in core vs old .net?